# Converting ISO8601 Time to 12 Hr Format

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

XSLT 2.0- Oxygen

```xml
<string>encounterDatetime</string>
<string>2020-04-05T16:36:00.000-0500</string>
<string>patient</string>
```

I need to use XSLT to convert this and display it in the main template. I've done a little bit with x path to find each piece of the time function. Beyond this, I'm afraid I don't know how to proceed. Admittedly, I'm terrible at xml. I only provided a little bit of the data. Here is what I have so far, I figured out the x pathing (I think) but am so stuck. I don't care if I have to get rid of the following code if you have a better solution.

```xml
<xsl:template name="TFTime">
    <xsl:param name="TS"/>
    <xsl:variable name="H" select="number(substring($TS, 1, 2))"/>
    <xsl:variable name="M" select="number(substring($TS, 4, 2))"/>
    <xsl:variable name="S" select="number(substring($TS, 7, 2))"/>

    <!-- how to proceed? -->

</xsl:template>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've tried using W3 schools, but I feel my skills aren't even adequate enough to comprehend their explanations.

Expected output would be something like this:

11:00 PM/AM

I don't need the seconds and I've already figured out how to extract the date.

On paper
t=0 then t+12

t>12 subtract 12 from time

do nothing if it's less than 12.

I have a feeling I should be using 11 here for convenience once I get to the part where I need to add AM and PM

Comment: **1.** Please edit your question and show the expected result. **2.** Do you know how to do this task using a pencil and paper?

Comment: *"If t>11 To=23:11 T=T-12"* Not sure what that means.

Comment: I just put it in the actual post, it wasn't formatting right here. Kinda struggling with the AM PM part

Comment: That's incorrect. You also need to convert 0:mm to 12:mm AM.

Comment: Updated the original post to represent that, I spaced that portion, thanks for keeping me in check.

Comment: i guess you're probably using an ancient XSLT 1.0 processor, otherwise this wouldn't be a problem. But we shouldn't have to guess: with XSLT questions, always say which version you are using (and make it clear if you really can't upgrade to 2.0 or 3.0). In fact it's best to tell us what processor you are using, because even some XSLT 1.0 processors have extensions to handle this.

Comment: And what do you intend to do with the offset (-0500 in your example)? Your expected output has nothing to do with the input. The output should be either 4:36 AM (local time) or 9:36 AM (UTC).

Comment: Regarding the offset, I already have that taken out of the DateTime string as </timezone>. Updated the post with xslt 2.0, I'm such a noob. I'm in oxygen.

Comment: In XSLT 2.0, this is a trivial task using the `format-dateTime()` function: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#format-date

Comment: I'll look into it. Thanks again.

Comment: When it asks for $value as xs:dateTime, is this asking for the location of the string in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To name it short, the `formate-dateTime()`function is what you are looking for, at least, if you are working in XSLT 2.0 (or above) as it it not available in XSLT 1.0.

The biggest problem in this context is, that your dateTime String does not comply with the `xs:dateTime` datatype defined in [W3C XML Schema Definition Language (XSD) 1.1 Part 2: Datatypes](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/) since it requires the timezone offset to be formatted `(+|-)HH:mm`, i.e. `-05:00` in your above example. There are two options to handle this problem:

1. considering you don't need the timezone information you can strip it from the string, as in `xs:dateTime` it is the only strippable parameter.
2. if you need the timezone information you would have to insert `:` as divider between hours and minutes.

I'll go forward with »1.«:

```xml
<xsl:template name="TFTime">
        <!-- a string that looks like a xs:dateTime except for the wrong timezone formatting -->
        <xsl:param name="TS" as="xs:string"/>
        <!-- cut the wrongly formatted timezone from the string and convert the string to xs:dateTime  -->
        <xsl:variable name="TS-noTimezone" select="xs:dateTime(substring($TS, 1, 23))" as="xs:dateTime"/>
        <!-- apply function format-dateTime($input, $pictureString)
             [h01] hour in the 12h realm (h), as two-digit (01)
             :     just a string
             [m01] minutes (m), as two-digit (01)
             [PN,2-2] a.m. / p.m. format (P), in capitals (N), exactly 2 characters long (,2-2), as otherwise it would contain colons
        -->
        <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime($TS-noTimezone, '[h01]:[m01] [PN,2-2]')"/>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. I eventually got it, but I was never able to do it with the format-DateTime function. I appreciate your input; now I know how to use this function. I also appreciate you fixing my post, I'm new to this whole thing. I'll be around though.